# "Overwrite Project Package" option in PackageMaker — What does it do?

Tags: cocoa, macos, packagemaker

PackageMaker's Project menu contains an "Overwrite Project Package" option.

I can't find any documentation of this option, nor any references to it online.

Does anybody know what its function is?